# Intel IOT with PLC

Tags: iot, intel-xdk, plc, intel-iot

just wondering if anyone has successfully used the [Intel IoT kit](https://software.intel.com/en-us/iot/home) to collect data from a PLC without an Arduino board? I.e. is OPC or similar supported. Thanks.

Comment: You tagged your questions with reference to the Intel XDK. Are you asking in the context of a Node.js IoT app? What sort of IoT hardware setup are you considering? Based on your question, I'm guessing you are currently working with a NUC + Arduino 101 acting as a slave I/O device, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is in the context of a Node.js app. We are considering an Intel Nuc. My question is if I can avoid using an Arduino board, i.e. has anyone collected data from Allen Bradley PLCs just using an Ethernet connection between the Nuc and PLC and if so what was the setup?

Comment: Yes, you can lose the Arudino, all it's doing is acting as an I/O extension for you NUC. It uses a piece of software called "[firmata](https://github.com/firmata/arduino)" that allows the underlying [mraa library](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/mraa) to make it appear as though the I/O on the Arduino is attached directly to the app running on your NUC. Your Node.js JavaScript code runs on your NUC. This [Node.js PLC library](https://github.com/plcpeople/nodepccc) could be used as a starting point. Or, if you have a Linux C lib for PLC comms, you could build a node_module on top of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a good option > http://node-opcua.github.io/ < which is also located here > https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua < under MIT license.

Searching for "opc for node" brings up a lot of interesting solutions.